# What is the use of struct cpufreq_policy in Linux Kernel CPU Frequency Subsystem

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86, cpu, power-management

I was reading about CPUFreq subsystem. There are two drivers

- Scaling Governors: Which decide what should be the next frequency to choose
- Scaling drivers: Which directly communicate with the hardware and set the frequency provided by scaling governors

Going through the various structures, i understood that

struct cpufreq_driver   -> Structure representing a scaling driver which talk to hardware and changes frequency

struct cpufreq_governor     -   Structure representing a CPU Frequency Governor

What is the use of the struct cpufreq_policy,  it is passed as a callback to all the members of struct cpufreq_governor?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it (read: I've taken a five minutes walk in the source tree), the [`struct cpufreq_policy`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/cpufreq.h#L51) is the state managed by the governors and handled to the scaling drivers.

It contains the frequency limits the governor works within, synchronization objects (eg `rwsem`), the frequency table, the CPUs affected by the policy and so on.

In this example of a governor [here](https://lwn.net/Articles/662209/), the policy is used to init some per-cpu structure that are probably used by the scaling driver.
Note that these drivers work basically in two modes: `target_index` where a frequency is set from an index in the frequency table (in the policy) and `set_policy` where the frequency limits are set for the hardware (i.e. HWP for Intel) or the software to operate within.

I've not quite grasped the full picture (that seems a lot of work) but I hope it's enough to get you started.